# How to prevent loading my Keras model at every time that I call the views in Django?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to use mobilenet in a Django app to classify images. I have already trained my model using Keras with Tensorflow backend and it is working properly without using Django. First I tried to use my model inside the view functions and it worked without any errors. However, the model is loaded every time I call this view and it takes a lot of times to reload. then I tried to define the model as a global model to load the weights only once. I have tried to initialize the model weights in the settings or in the app.py file but many problems were shown up. actually I tried to use the model without loading the weights and it worked but after loading the weight it gives me this error:
this is my code:
in settings.py

```
global model,graph
model = MobileNet(weights=None)
model.load_weights(path)
model._make_predict_function()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

in views.py

```
 with graph.as_default():
          model.predict(img)
```

and this is the error

```
RuntimeError at /classifier/
Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

and this is the error before adding model._make_predict_function():

```
 Error while reading resource variable conv_pw_12/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/conv_pw_12/kernel)
     [[{{node conv_pw_12/Conv2D/ReadVariableOp}}]]
```

and here are the versions of the installed packages:

```
Django==3.0.3
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
numpy==1.18.1
Pillow==7.0.0
scipy==1.4.1
tensorboard==2.1.0
tensorflow-cpu==2.1.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.1.0
```

one more thing, my weights are saved as .h5 file.
thanks